# Extending BigDecimal?

Tags: java, design-patterns, static-methods

I've a fair bit of code using `BigDecimal` Class and I hate the clumsiness of the interface.

I've alleviated the pain of using `BigDecimal`s with integers by creating a helper class with static methods with the following methods:

```
compare(BigDecimal first, int second)
divide(BigDecimal dividend, BigDecimal divisor, int scale)
divide(BigDecimal dividend, int divisor, int scale)
divide(int divident, int divisor, int scale)
multiply(BigDecimal first, BigDecimal second, int scale)
multiply(BigDecimal first, int second, int scale)
multiply(int first, int second, int scale)
zeroPad(BigDecimal value, int totalLength, int scale)
```

That's all I need for now and the code is a little more readable than before. However, I read that static methods are a "bad" thing and that they don't follow OO-principles.

If I extend `BigDecimal` however, I'd define a new type and thus I'd have to re-define all methods to wrap them with my object or I won't be able to use the results with the augmented methods. It doesn't seem a smart thing to do.

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: Interesting, I've made almost exactly the same static methods in my code. To me, it's crazy that `BigDecimal` doesn't have a `.divide(BigDecimal dividend, int divisor)` method built-in. When was the last time you needed to divide anything by a decimal? I've never had anything but `int` as the divisor in any of my code's calculations. (not saying the cases don't exist, but `int` as the divisor seems like the most likely scenario that it'd be worth including in the standard library).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it exactly as you have!

All design decisions of this type must be based on a wish to make the code more maintainable for the next programmer that will take over the code after you. Which is why we make O-O design and component based development in the first place.

But given the syntax of Java, it is really difficult to make an API for math-based expressions. I have two problems with the current BigInteger API:

- it is not very close to the usual math-notation
- it is asymmetric for symmetric operators like add and multiply

[Operator-overload is one of the few features of C++, I miss in Java]

Which is more readable?

```java
BigInteger a = ...;
BigInteger b = ...;
BigInteger c = divide(a, b);
```

or

```java
BigInteger a = ...;
BigInteger b = ...;
BigInteger c = a.divide(b);
```

Personally, I prefer the second version.

Worse is the cases where numbers of different base types are part of the same expression. E.g.

```java
int a = ...;
BigInteger b = ...;
BigInteger c = divide(a, b);
```

or

```java
int a = ...;
BigInteger b = ...;
BigInteger c = BigInteger.valueOf(a).divide(b);
```

Also consider the big differences in the notations from the small changes in the corresponding math notation:

- `(a-b)*c` is translated to `a.subtract(b).multiply(c)` or `multiply(subtract(a,b),c)`
- `c*(a-b)` is translated to `c.multiply(a.subtract(b))` or `multiply(c,subtract(a,b))`

For me, it is easier to write and read the static method notation, than the "pure" O-O based notation.

Comment: I guess that after all is the simplest safer way, because if I wrap BigDecimal, it won't work with JDBC any more.

Answer (score 4):

Don't extend `BigDecimal`, use a wrapper class around it (like you have) or another framework like Commons Math.

`Dfp` looks similar to what you want - org.apache.commons.math.dfp.Dfp

Comment: I'll take a look to Dfp. So a wrapper class would contain a BigDecimal inside the object I guess, and since is unrelated to BigDecimal I'd have to rewrite all the methods delegating to BigDecimal plus all my methods. How could this approach be superior? It seems roughly the same effort of extending BigDecimal. Just trying to understand, I'd be happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: Thinking more it would be superior, because I don't need to provide all the methods, only the one I need and so I'd not mix MyBigDecimal and BigDecimal instances.

Comment: Link to org.apache.commons.math.dfp.Dfp is not longer valid

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Could you please clarify to me what do you mean exactly with "I'd define a new type and thus I'd have to re-define all methods to wrap them with my object or I won't be able to use the results with the augmented methods."?</strike>

- If you need to use *most* of the methods from BigDecimal API, plus your own additional methods, then I'd suggest you inherit your custom class from BigDecimal. In this way, you do not need to define wrappers for the BigDecimal methods that already work fine for you. This scenario is the one where your custom class **is a** BigDecimal, plus something more.
- If you need just a *few* methods from BigDecimal API, plus your own additional methods, then I'd suggest you **do not** derive from BigDecimal. Instead you *use* internally a BigDecimal, and you *delegate* to it some of the functionalities exposed by your custom API. This scenario is the one where your custom class **has a** BigDecimal, but it's not a BigDecimal.

Then in order to wrap a BigDecimal method to return your custom type:

With inhertance, you'd do something like the following:

```
@Override public MyBD divide(int second)
{
    return new MyBD( this.divide(second) );
}
```

With delegation (i.e. composition), you'd do:

```
public MyBD divide(int second)
{
    return new MyBD( _innerBigDecimal.divide(second) );
}
```

With static helper methods, you'd do:

```
public static BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal first, int second)
{
    return first.divide(second);
}
```

Comment: For instance if I define MyBigDecimal extends BigDecimal if I use a method defined in the base class it will return a BigDecimal and thus code like this won't work:

new MyBigDecimal("12.89").divide(AnotherBigDecimal).methodOfMyBigDecimal()

Comment: ok, got it. So yes, you should wrap the original BigDecimal methods you need with your own version. Just notice that this _wrapping job_ has to be done whichever choice you take, whether it's inheritance, delegation, but also with your static helper functions you're doing that!

Answer (score 0):

If you create a class that extends another class (i.e. BigDecimal in your case), the child class still has all properties of the parent (super) class. In your case, if you write:

```
public class UsableBigDecimal extends BigDecimal {
...
}
```

any UsableBigDecimal objects would still be instances of BigDecimal, since it's their superclass. You would be able to use them as you would any BigDecimal object, your static utility methods included.

That said, static utility methods are, in my opinion, quite acceptable as a way to share common code when dealing with core Java classes.

Comment: MyBigDecimal would be an instance of BigDecimal and could be used as such, but not the opposite, so if I call a method of the base class on the derived class it returns a new base class instance and I can't use the derived class methods any more on it (except with a copy constructor, but that would make the code even more clumsy).

Answer (score -4):

I would forget about this problem, and the original problem, and get used to the API of BigDecimal as it is. All you're doing is creating problems for yourself, as the existence of this question demonstrates.

Comment: Let's say I want to use a fixed format to display all decimals, ideally I will override toString. Natural way of doing this is extending BigDecimal, but it requires to override its constructors too therefore I prefer to wrap it.

Comment: @LluisMartinez The natural way to do that is actually to write a new Format class. `toString()` is only a debugging toy.